# Why no Azure Portal Activity Log events recorded for deleted Containers?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I create a new Cosmos DB (SQL API) container, I see events "Write SQL Database" and "Write SQL Container" in the Azure Portal - Activity Log. However, I don't see any event logged when I delete the Container. Am I missing something, or perhaps can someone explain why delete events are not deemed relevant for logging?

Comment: How are you creating and deleting the container? Are you doing it in the portal or using another means?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? It can help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Updated 0507:

I just got back from the support team, here are details:

If you want to audit various operations of end-users' performing, you need to disable the key-based metadata write access on your account.

Once disable it, Cosmos DB will prevent accessing the account via account keys, and only the user with the proper Role-based access control(RBAC) role and credentials can change to any resource within the account.

This is by-designed behavior, you can refer more detail on this [documents](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fcosmos-db%2Faudit-control-plane-logs%23control-plane-operations-for-database-or-containers&data=02%7C01%7Cv-ivyang%40microsoft.com%7C6bc4c83df8de44c9659c08d7f1a3e335%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637243558512355086&sdata=DEIcE7nvJyPnVBbyQeerzLnFNGHnQLVeMwFzO2jAmdU%3D&reserved=0):

The code below is used to enable sending **delete container** logs to Activity logs:

## Disable key based metadata write access via CLI :

```
$subscriptionid = "xxx"
$resourceGroupName = "xxx"
$accountName = "xx"
$databaseName = "xx"
$containerName = "xx"

az account set --subscription $subscriptionid
az cosmosdb update  --name $accountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --disable-key-based-metadata-write-access true
```

## delete SQL container via CLI

```
az cosmosdb sql container delete --account-name $accountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --database-name $databaseName --name $containerName
```

Then in Activity logs:

[image]

**Important Note**: If you use azure cli to disable key based metadata write access, then you cannot use UI(azure portal) to delete a container, you should use azure cli to do it. And if you want to perform it via UI, you need to enable it via azure cli command by setting `false` to `--disable-key-based-metadata-write-access`